# SQL Server 2012 Collapse / Unpivot Two Columns Into One?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot, cartesian-product

Actual table has about 6 million rows, num1 and num2 in each row represent numeric boundaries. I need to convert the two-column set into a single column, and applying the to each of the two rows that previously shared a single row. Below is a small sample. I looked at Unpivot examples but nothing seems to fit what I need. Can anyone recommend the right way to go? I realize I will end up with 12 million rows in the end.

Thanks.

```
declare @orig table ( num1 bigint , num2 bigint , metakey tinyint )
insert into @orig 
select 7216,7471  , 0
union all
select 7472,8239  , 1
union all
select 8240,9263  , 2
union all
select 9264,11311 , 3


declare @dest table ( allnum bigint , metakey tinyint )

    -- Wanted result set:
/*
    select * from @dest
    7216        0
    7471        0
    7472        1
    8239        1
    8240        2
    9263        2
    9264        3
    11311       3
*/
```

I understand that this works for my table variable sample, but for the really big set it does not smell right:

```
insert into @dest
select num1 , metakey
from @orig
union all 
select num2 , metakey
from @orig
order by 1
```

Comment: No, there are no other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unpivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) seams to do what you want.

```
select u.allnum,
       u.metakey
from @orig as o
  unpivot (allnum for col in (o.num1, o.num2)) as u
```

Compared to the union query you already have this should be faster because it will only scan the table once instead of twice.

Comment: That does it, but I did have to throw in a Distinct keyword in a later statement to get rid of dupes in an edge case (not in my original post) with values of 7214,7214, as my Union implictly filtered them out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using cross apply

```
select allnum,metakey from @orig cross apply (values(num1 ), (num2)) x(allnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do a two step process, you could do this:

```
insert @dest (bigint, metakey)
    select num1, metakey from @orig

insert @dest (bigint, metakey)
    select num2, metakey from @orig
```

If that's not an option, you could do a similar thing by selecting from a derived table, which would be comprised of a union of the two selects above.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your second block of text before I answered.

Comment: You can delete your comment if you want to.